# HTML table cell with width less than 1% percent

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table, html-email

Wondering if it is possible to somehow specify a table cell's width in the form of a percentage less than 1%. In XHTML 1.0 strict, without the use of CSS.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="middle">
<td width="70%">..</td>
<td width="0.5%"></td>
<td width="0.5%"></td>
<td width="29%">..</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is this possible? Is it valid? Does it work cross-platform? Anyone know of a way? When I attempt to use the code above, it appears to interpret `5%` and not a half percent.

The template will be for consumption in email clients, not a web browser.

Comment: I would imagine that the program used to view the result(s) only know hows to read integers (e.g. "0.1%" is read as "1%" and "0.9%" is read as "9%"?) ... if so then the only such possibly valid value is "0%". I am not sure how XHTML defines the attribute, though.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. I really hate to mix pixel and percent widths but I guess I might have to. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Some browsers have better support of decimal values for percents and pixels, but I think only fractional ems are universally supported, so you're safer using a whole percent.

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason to do this. What are you doing?

Comment: I've styled the first of the `width="0.5%"` columns with `border-right: 1px`, to give a hairline separator between the larger 70%/30% columns, and want a very slight amount of padding surrounding the separation line. That particular row is one of many rows, and so I can't arbitrarily add padding left/right to just the columns in this row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try taking the middle two at 0.5% and making a single TD at 1%. Then put a table inside at 100% and have two TD's each at 50%.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="middle">
<td width="70%">..</td>
<td width="1%">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr valign="middle">
<td width="50%"></td>
<td width="50%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="29%">..</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Now here's a creative solution! +1 just for the idea. You'd think with all the nested tables I have already in this template, it might have occurred to me. Thinking this will work, and if so I'll be sure to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS.....
Try this!

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="middle">
<td style="width:70%">..</td>
<td style="width:0.5%"></td>
<td style="width:0.5%"></td>
<td style="width:29%">..</td>
</tr>
</table>
```